# How do I avoid overflows when implementing RSA?

Tags: python, encryption, unicode

### Background:

Using python 3. Trying not to use other modules

I encountered a difficulty in writing a simple RSA algorithm. I want to convert a string (each character is in ascii) into a single number for encryption.

My code is as follows:

```
# convert string to num
num = 0
for i in string:
    num = num*128 + ord(i)
```

```
# convert num to string
string = []
while num:
    string.append(chr(num % 128))
    num //= 128
string.reverse()
string = "".join(string)
```

Two codes using pow()
(p and q is prime between 2^1023 + 1 to 2^1024 - 1):

```
e = 65537
r = (p-1)*(q-1)
n = p*q
d = modInverse(e, r)

ciphertext = pow(num, e, n)

num = pow(ciphertext, d, n)

def modInverse(a, b):
    oldS = 1
    s = 0
    r = b
    while b!=0:
        q = a//b
        a, b = b, a % b
        oldS, s = s, oldS - q*s

    while oldS <= 0:
        oldS += r

    return oldS
```

### Question:

1. I think my code is too complicated (Especially the second one), is there a more concise way in python?
2. When I use a string of about 150 characters and use the above code to convert it into a number, the number seems to be too large, causing python's pow() function to overflow (Or it is larger than the modulus and cannot be decrypted correctly.). How can I solve it? (I only thought of using arrays to save in segments. Is there a better way?)
3. (solved) How can I make it support unicode chars?

Comment: Show the code that uses `pow`, but I suspect floating point is used along the way, and it only has 53 bits of accuracy.

Comment: RSA is based on modular arithmetic and `pow` has an optional modulus argument. Python's `pow` is able to handle real-world public keys with hundreds of digits. If you have overflow, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: A separate issue is that if the plaintext is, when converted to a number, bigger than the modulus then you would be unable to decrypt, but that is a different problem from actual overflow.

Comment: @JohnColeman "A separate issue is that if the plaintext is, when converted to a number, bigger than the modulus then you would be unable to decrypt, but that is a different problem from actual overflow." I think that would be the actual problem, how can I deal with it?

Comment: You could break the message up into blocks and encrypt each block separately. This makes RSA a block cipher. I assume that this is a toy implementation so that it doesn't really matter exactly what you do, but if you want to do it more seriously then you would have to delve into questions of padding and what block cipher confidentiality mode to use. People seldom go that route and mostly use RSA to encrypt keys for symmetric ciphers such as AES which do the actual encryption/decryption.

Comment: Because RSA is not meant for encrypting especially information way larger than the modulus. We use RSA for digital signature as RSASSA-PSS or for Key Encapsulation Mechanism as RSA-KEM then encrypted with Data Encapsulation Mechanism as AES-GCM with the key,

Comment: Since python 3.8 you can replace your entire `modInverse(a, b)` function with a single function call `pow(a, -1, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll have to start from the last point first:

You can support all of Unicode by choosing a encoding for your characters, i.e. a way to turn the codepoint values (that you get with `ord()`) to a sequence of bytes. I'd recommend [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). You turn a string to bytes with [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode).

Then, you can use [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) to efficiently encode a bytestring to an integer:

```
>>> b = "Héllo wörld!".encode("utf-8")
>>> x = int.from_bytes(b, "little")
677275896233612098044811910169416
```

Similarly, you can use [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) to reverse that, i.e. get a byte sequence from an integer. (The `bit_length()` magic is a recipe straight from the docs, linked above.)

```
>>> y = x.to_bytes((x.bit_length() + 7) // 8, "little")
b'H\xc3\xa9llo w\xc3\xb6rld!'
```

and then [`.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) that back to a text string.

```
>>> z = y.decode("utf-8")
'Héllo wörld!'
```

Comment: The last problem is indeed solved. Where can I check the principles of these functions? The attached link only seems to give the behavior

Comment: Well, if you insist, you can find the C implementations [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec382fac0db6d9159c2d3496a70b7a605545957e/Objects/longobject.c#L5608) and [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec382fac0db6d9159c2d3496a70b7a605545957e/Objects/longobject.c#L5546)...